# Why don't YouTube take legal actions on YouTube downloader sites/applications?

Tags: legal-research, youtube

if they don't/won't do,then why does some youtube downloader apps thrown out of the PlayStore (Tubemate, Vidmate etc ..)?

if they do, why there are plethora of web sites/apps doing still doing it?

Comment: Whether certain apps are taken out of the respective app stores is not a legal judgment. I'm pretty sure most app stores reserve the right to take out anything in their terms of service. To take down a web site or app, you'd probably have to take actual legal action.

Comment: so, after all what would you say? is it legal or illegal downloading a youtube video?

Comment: I think the answer is here already. TLDR; It is against the YouTube T&S but not a "crime" (your term illegal seems to imply crime): [Why are there so many youtube to mp4 and mp3 download websites online when it is illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/why-are-there-so-many-youtube-to-mp4-and-mp3-download-websites-online-when-it-is)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the ratio of impact level / easiness to take them down. In other words, worthiness of bothering.

A mobile app will have a bigger impact and is much easier to throw out of the Playstore compared to websites which will have smaller audiences and are more difficult to take off the web. If Youtube learns that any particular website offering downloads is causing enough revenue loss, surely they will care of it.