# Is it okay to commercially use Youtube videos that have creative commons license?

Tags: copyright, copyfraud

Sometimes, more than one youtube channel upload the same video under different licenses. Different licenses can be "Standard youtube license" and "creative commons".

If I reused that video, will I get a copyright strike because it's under Standard youtube license on one of the channels? Or is it okay to use it because it's under creative commons so any other channel (including mine) can use it?

What I'm going to do is to use part of the video as to complement my main video.

**Edit**:

Actually, it's not the answer that I was looking for because that question asks about a single video on youtube. I'm talking about more than one copy on different channels. some copies are creative commons and other copies are standard youtube license.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to download and modify videos from YouTube licensed under creative Commons?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8033/is-it-legal-to-download-and-modify-videos-from-youtube-licensed-under-creative-c)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Actually, it's not the answer that I was looking for because that question asks about a single video on youtube. I'm talking about more than one copy on different channels. some copies are creative commons and other copies are standard youtube license.

Comment: Don't assume all the copies are legal. Find the original upload and see what the license is. If you can't determine that, you run the risk of infringement.

Comment: Check which Creative Commons license.  There are several.  If it has -NC in it, you don't have permission for commercial use.  I'm unfamiliar with the standard Youtube license, but I'd bet it doesn't give permission for commercial use.

Comment: Remember that the license is not actually defined by the "license" field in the YouTube interface. For example, someone may post a video saying it is under a restrictive license but the copyright owner can always give you special permission to post it yourself. That giving of permission is what actually determines the license. Also, remember that people posting videos may not bother with the "license" property of the YouTube upload, so probably they just leave whatever the default option is, even though the video may in fact be CC licensed.

Comment: "Will I get a copyright strike" - This is not a legal question. 'Copyright strikes' are purely a mechanism that YouTube uses and is largely an automated process. They have no legal significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copyrighted material can operate under several licences

Assuming that the person who uploaded the video has the right to grant licences (i.e. they are the copyright holder or have a licence that is permissive about re-licencing) then they are free to offer as many different licences as they want. For example, many pieces of software offer different commercial and non-commercial versions that may be functionally the same or different.

If you want to reuse the material and one of the licences allows your use case then you must abide by that licence. The fact that your usage breaches a different licence is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which copy of the video you use.

Does the copy that you want to re-use allow you to do what you want to do?

Also, just because loads of people upload the same video under different licences to different channel doesn't necessarily mean they're entitled to do that in the first place. In which case you aren't entitled to use it at all (ie copyright infringement).

You'll want to keep documentary evidence of where you obtained the video, so that you:

1. show where you obtained the copy you are using from
2. can defend a copyright infringement claim (if you are able to - see the preceding paragraph).