# is creating an app/website/software which uses youtube-dl for videos download from YouTube legal?

Tags: copyright, music, youtube

I'm pretty sure that it won't be legal in some or the work way. 
However, I want to clarify my doubt about legal issues again.

I read this article about it - [is it legal to download youtube videos?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1648/30557)

My plan is to create a software/app which has **youtube-dl** as a core piece to download videos from YouTube. It is open source and can be used commercially. Initially thought to have lot of features in the app for example *playlists*, but ultimately the app will download videos in **user's desktop or mobile phones** from YouTube via youtube-dl. Mostly it will be music download.

I'm thinking that the app creator will **play a mediator role** (between user and YouTube) when it comes to legal issues, as youtube-dl can be pointed in terms of backend legal issues and app users will be responsible to not *share/distribute/reproduce* the downloaded video, including other terms & conditions (if this statement is right).

Is it safe to assume that app creator will be a mediator and won't face any legal issues? This is my doubt.

In life this is not the case - As the mediator person who pick up drugs from one person and give to another person, is also considered as criminal.

On the contrary side - If a courier company (mediator) picks up drugs from one person and deliver it to another person (in a totally unidentifiable & protective wrapping which they cannot open legally), not sure they'll also be considered as criminals.

Not sure what to believe and should I go ahead to build such software & mobile app?

Comment: What about creating a windows application and getting users to download from my website, where there is no mediator like play store in between?