# (EU) Is it legal to record youtube assuming I can use copyrighted content in question legally?

Tags: terms-of-service, youtube

Hello I want to record youtube video using either screen recorder, assuming that recorded content can and will be used legally as far as copyright goes.

Now their rules say something like:

"you are not allowed to access, reproduce, download, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, alter, modify or otherwise use any part of the Service or any Content except: (a) as specifically permitted by the Service;  (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the respective rights holders; or (c) as permitted by applicable law;"

I'm in EU, Poland, so it is currently different document than one used in US.

So c) clause may mean either that rest of this paragraph applies only to anyway illegal activity like unauthorized copying of copyrighted movies or music (I am allowed to use content, thus I am allowed to get it somehow and screen recorder has nothing to do with their app). Or it may mean that I am allowed to "use" given content legally, but I can't use youtube to get content to my disk. The latter seems absurd as it makes scholarship or criticism impossible or dependent on youtube written consents.

EDIT: I am referring to document here https://www.youtube.com/t/terms it's content may vary depending on your location I think.

Comment: Did [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-downloading-youtube-videos-legal) not satisfy you?

Comment: Is there another part of the TOS which says what the service specifically permits?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica apparently this is different document that I am subject to in EU.

Comment: The difference in the document might be the result of changes; the other question and answer are 6 years old, and most companies revise their terms of service fairly frequently.

Comment: @ohwillieke there must be something somewhere, because if there weren't, this clause would prevent everyone from using YouTube without explicit written permission: ("you are not allowed to access [...] or otherwise use any part of the Service or any Content except: (a) as specifically permitted by the Service; (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the respective rights holders; or (c) as permitted by applicable law;" -- unless the vague item (c) is the basis for the normal use case of watching videos posted on YouTube.

Comment: Sorry for not bringing it up earlier @phoog  
"You may access and use the Service as made available to you, as long as you comply with this Agreement and the law. You may view or listen to Content for your personal, non-commercial use. You may also show YouTube videos through the embeddable YouTube player."

It is another vague thing - like is it just watching or showing, or whatever use "as made available to you".